# ASP.net Authentication Issue on Particular Folder

Tags: .net, authentication, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a website hosted in IIS 7.5.7600.16385, on a Windows Server 2008R2 machine, the website works fine except for one particular folder containing pages which display DevEx reports - whenever I try to access one of these pages, the browser requests login credentials.  I currently have Authentication settings as follows:

Anonymous Authentication: Enabled, Anonymous user id set to custom account.
ASP .NET Impersonation: Enabled, impersonating custom account
Windows authentication: Enabled, NTLM provider preferred.
The app pool is using the ApplicationPoolIdentity.

I realise these are probably not normal authentication settings, have read that only windows authentication should be enabled, but with those settings none of the pages are accessible.  The custom account is the owner of the whole directory the website resides in, has every possible permission to the folder and I have propagated the permissions to child folders from the root site folder.

If anyone could please advise regarding this issue,  or direct me to a resource which may help, it would be appreciated a LOT. Have tried everything I can think of to get the server to authenticate internally on this folder and nothing has worked.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will help but look at [documentation of security element of system.webServer section](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security). It seems that you can set different authentication on specific pages/directories in web.config of the web page like

```
<location path="yourdirectory">
   <system.webServer>
      <security>
         <authentication>
            <windowsAuthentication enabled="false" />
            <basicAuthentication enabled="false" />
            <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
         </authentication>
      </security>
   </system.webServer>
</location>
```